# New to VB.NET - "Expected end of statement" error

Tags: vb.net

I'm simply trying to create an array of integers:

```
Dim amenities() as Integer
amenities=New Integer(){1,2,3,4,5}
```

And I'm getting this error:

**Expected end of statement**

**Dim amenities() as Integer**

**-----------------------^**

It says the error is happening on "as", but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I feel stupid asking, but I'm stuck.

Comment: try to check if you have not missed something 'else in the code, just as you have posted in the array, and proper. Bye

Comment: As an aside, there is no reason (and reason not) to separate declaration and initialisation. Always declare variables on first use (and not earlier!) and coalesce the two lines into `Dim amenities As Integer() = New Integer() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` – or, shorter: `Dim amenities = New Integer() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code above as you have posted it. The error is elsewhere.

Comment: I agree, nothing wrong with the code posted, assuming the assignment is in a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amenities is the variable name. So your declaration should read:

```
Dim amenities as Integer()
```

Comment: Hmmm, that still didn't work. I get the same error, on "as" again

Comment: This answer is logically correct (and arrays *should* be declared like this) but the other code should actually also work; at least it used to (but perhaps you needed to supply an explicit dimension then; I don’t remember).

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code using VS2010 and targeting Frameworks 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0 and in all cases your code works:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim amenities() As Integer
        amenities = New Integer() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    End Sub
End Module
```

In fact this syntax is also valid:

```
Dim amenities As Integer()
amenities = New Integer() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

But if you want to 1 line your code you need the first syntax:

```
Dim amenities() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```